# What is the interstellar density of mm sized "dust" particles?

Tags: space-travel, interstellar-matter

If you assume an interstellar spacecraft of 100 m in diameter traveling to the nearest star - that ship would plow through 3 x 10^20 m^3 of interstellar space.  At 0.5 c the energy release of such a spaceship encountering a piece of space "dust" weighing (~0.01g) becomes significant. Only one such impact would be enough to cause severe spacecraft damage given the kinetic energy involved (150,000 Joules).  This collision would explode like a pinpoint bomb (30 g of TNT - one half the charge in a hand grenade).

So, what are the chances of such a space ship encountering such a interstellar grain of dust in traveling to the nearest star?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interstellar dust/matter distribution](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71358/)

Comment: also, the nearest star to us is the Sun...

Comment: Your calculation seems to be of by several orders of magnitude. Even at non-relativistic speeds of around $0.01c$ I get around $45\;\mathrm{MJ}$ impact energy for a $0.01\;\mathrm{g}$ particle.