# Interstellar Debris

Tags: astronomy, density, interstellar-matter

Do radio astronomers not have solid data on just how dense and widely distributed solid interstellar debris is? I cannot seem to find any direct answer on this subject from any source. I am interested in this as it could be quite an obstacle for interstellar travel without good sensors.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you specify radio astronomy? In some mass ranges I’m fairly sure that’s not the best observational technique.

Comment: Related (probably dupe of) https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71358/25301

Comment: This is too vague. The answer to the current question is "Yes, they do".

Comment: Maybe this is better for Astronomy.SE? That might give more precise answers.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answers. Well, I didn't mean only radio astronomy, we all know about all the great telescopes and their multi-mode optical lensing techniques etc.. The thing is Rob, still haven't seen any concrete data on how much interstellar debris there is in even one good example, say from here to a system only 12 light years away say....   -  I have the Electromagnetic Propulsion and Spacecraft Designs to Boot ANYWHERE in the galaxy and beyond, but a definite estimate is obviously important. And not just for rogue planets and moons, rocks big enough to destroy a spacecraft say etc...

Comment: " ..... data on just how dense and widely distributed solid interstellar debris is? "   - I think   " ...dense and widely distributed "  isn't very vague,  ya know...how widely distributed in Any Direction type thing, Obviously. Cmon, easy to grasp.

Comment: This is a Major, MAJOR issue for Space Travel. And it needs the Same Type of Definitive Mapping as all the Star and Galaxy Clusters have been mapped. The Sensor Systems I am Designing would certainly need to be programmed properly with the correct positional Data to guide the Omni-Directional Propulsion System I have for the Craft to adjust and readjust course quite Quickly on any flight. Sure, it is SERIOUS. Anyways, thanks for the responses. I hope I get more.  Astronomy.SE? Okeeee, I can check that as well, thks Anders.  -  Katrina.